# Files(audio or video) form newly created folder in resources doesn't access by R. method in android studio

Tags: java, android

[image]

and this file is not showing in R. files
[image]

Comment: Put your files into `values/raw` folder. And then get `R.raw.file_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly android audio and video files store in raw folder. You need to create it. Create it in same hierarchy as drawable file. Then put your audio or video track there. Then you can access it via `R.raw.music` like that.

if it is not accessible from above mention method. You can use below code segment for it.

```
int resourceID =getResources().getIdentifier(YourFileName, "raw", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Right Click on res folder and select new --> Android Resource Directory

    Select raw and click on Ok.

    Paste your audio and video file here then you can access this files.

    For Audio/Mp3

    int [] resID= {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3};
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID[position]);

    mediaPlayer.start();

or

int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```